# How to trigger max value of field from multiple child objects onto parent account?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact, childrecords

At my org, we have FICO scores for each contact in an account. Some accounts have multiple contacts, while others have one. I am trying to pull the highest contact FICO Credit Score into a custom account field called Account FICO Status. I am brand new to salesforce, so my coding techniques are border line miserable, but I have developed the following:

```
trigger accountFico on Contact (after update, after insert) {

        Map<Id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>();
        List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

        for(Contact childObj : Trigger.new) {
            listIds.add(childObj.accountId);
        }

        parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account> ([Select Id, account_Fico_Status__c, (Select Id, fico_Credit_Score__c from Contact) from Account where Id in :listIds]);

        for(Contact cont : Trigger.new) {    
            Account myParentAcc = parentAccs.get(cont.Account);
            myParentAcc.accountFicoStatus = Max(cont.fico_Credit_Score__c);
        }

        update parentAccs.values();


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ishwar Mete's answer is close, but continues to have some issues.

I do agree that using SOQL Aggregate Functions is the way to go here. Aggregate Functions:

- Are provided by Salesforce, so their behavior is well tested and documented
- Handle null values without issues, save for one edge case (unlike apex)
- Help make your code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

The following code should work as the body of your trigger:

```
// My preference for aggregating related record Ids is to use a Set<Id>
//    instead of a List<Id>. This will make it easier to remove nulls.
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

for(Contact con :Trigger.new){
    accountIds.add(con.AccountId);
}

// It will cause issues later (when we update) if we have a null in this set. 
// This ensures we will not have a null value in the set.
// This can be accomplished in other ways (such as using an `if` block in the loop above), 
//    but I believe this to be the fastest.
accountIds.remove(null);

for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId, MAX(fico_Credit_Score__c) maxScore
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
            GROUP BY AccountId]){

    // We can set the Id of an sObject if we pass it into that sObject's constructor.
    // This is a common pattern used for updating records of related sObjects,
    //    and saves us from needing to write another query
    accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
        Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'),
        // When fetching an aggregated field, it comes back as an instance of Object.
        // Thus, it's required to cast the result. Number field type = Decimal
        accountFicoStatus = (Decimal)ar.get('maxScore')
    ));
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```

The difference between our two answers is as follows:

- In my solution, we largely take the first portion of the code you provided in your question. We gather all of the `AccountId` in a set, and use that set as the sole condition in the `WHERE` clause of the query.

  - We can't use `Trigger.new` in the `WHERE` clause because that would
    cause us to only calculate the max FICO score of the contacts being
    inserted or updated instead of the max FICO score of all contacts
    under a given `Account`. Something like getting a local maximum of a mathematical function instead of the absolute maximum.
- I alias the aggregate function result. Not necessary, but gives more context compared to `expr0`. Helpful if your query is long or if you use multiple aggregate functions
- I cast the result of the aggregate function as a `Decimal` (which corresponds to the `Number` field type). This should resolve the compilation issue you were having with the corresponding line in Ishwar Mete's answer.

One quirk to watch out for when using SOQL Aggregate Functions is that, the last time I tested this (4 months ago), if none of the records being aggregated have a value in the field that you're trying to aggregate, the result of the aggregation will be `null`. In other words, the SOQL Aggregate Functions are not completely coalescing nulls.

If your FICO score field on `Account` has a default value, explicitly setting that field to null will overwrite that default value. If you don't want that to happen (or need to do more math with the aggregated result), you can use the ternary condition operator to manually coalesce a null result.

The following line

```
accountFicoStatus = (Decimal)ar.get('maxScore')
```

would become

```
// syntax is <boolean test> ? <value if test passes> : <value if test fails>
accountFicoStatus = ar.get('maxScore') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('maxScore')
```

Comment: *This should resolve the compilation issue you were having with*
Looks like you left us hanging on your final bullet.

Comment: I suppose that's what I get for trying to divide my attention amongst 5 different

Comment: Thank you so much. The local maximum is a perfect description. I was tinkering with it all weekend trying to get an absolute, but I'm not familiar enough with apex yet. I appreciate your time and the help. @DerekF

Answer (score 1):

Use of Aggregate function in SOQL will be the best solution for this case,

```
trigger accountFico on Contact (after update, after insert) {

        List<AggregateResult> contactAggrList = [SELECT AccountId, max(fico_Credit_Score__c) 
                                                 FROM Contact 
                                                 WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New
                                                 AND AccountId <> null
                                                 Group By AccountId];

        List<Account> accountsToUPdate = new List<Account>();

        for(AggregateResult contactAggr : contactAggrList) {
            accountsToUPdate.add(new Account(Id = (Id)contactAggr.get('AccountId'),
                                             accountFicoStatus = (Integer)contactAggr.get('expr0'))); //Assuming fico_Credit_Score__c is Integer if not typecast to that type

        }

        update accountsToUPdate;
}
```

I have added this code directly into trigger but best practice is to add it into the handler class.

Comment: `.get()` needs a string. You should use `.get('AccountId')`.

Comment: This solution may not always return the correct result as is. You'll need to iterate over `Trigger.new` and build a list or a map of Account Ids, and use that in the WHERE clause instead of the Ids from `Trigger.new` to guarantee that the query returns the absolute max for all contacts related to a given account.

Comment: Thanks so much for the post. I tested that one, but got an unexpected token error on 'where', but I will try the trigger.new out now. Thanks again for the help y'all.

Comment: @Connner Check it now, I have updated the code and its working

Comment: @IshwarMete Thanks again for all of the help. I am receiving a message saying that the variable "contactList" at line 10 column 43 does not exist. Would I need to define the variable first?

Comment: @Conner I am really sorry for this I just typed code on browser but it should work now

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid initial expression type for field Account.Id, expecting: Id at line 11 column 51 
Please, don't apologize. You're doing me a huge favor. it is much appreciated. I received the error message above. Is the account(id supposed to be account.id on line 11? @IshwarMete

Comment: Looking at all the compile time errors i think I need to test it once in org.

Comment: Its finally done.

Comment: @IshwarMete No error message. Will be testing it out soon. You are a god send my dear friend. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: @IshwarMete Hey Ishwar, the code is syntactically sound. I'm receiving the error: "System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer: ()" I've added .intValue() just about everywhere I can think of, but it is an incorrect method. Any recommendations, if you have a free second?

Comment: @conner At which line you are getting this error

Comment: My apologies for the untimeliness of this response, but I get that error message when I attempt to create a new contact with a integer credit score. @IshwarMete

Comment: accountFico: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer: () @IshwarMete

Comment: I am not getting any error, are you using the same code as I have given? If not plz use the the code as it is?

Comment: If you are using it as it is sent me details of data type of both fields on account and contact and the exact line at which you are getting error.@Conner

Comment: @IshwarMete the only thing I changed on the code was on line 13. I changed accountFicoStatus to account_Fico_Status__c. Both Account FICO Status and FICO Credit Score fields are number fields (3,0). When I go to create a new contact with a credit score, I receive this message after saving: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger accountFico caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: accountFico: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer: ()

Comment: @IshwarMete a little more background if this helps(and thank you again for all of your help): each contact has their own page accessible through the account page. Each contact has a field for FICO Credit Score and I'm trying to update the Account FICO Status with the value of the highest credit score from the contacts related to their account. For the sake of transparency, if X has a score of 500 and Y has a score of 600, I would want the Account FICO Status field to say 600.

Comment: Contact X and Contact Y**, so it would select the contact with the highest credit score and place their credit score value in the account credit status field. @IshwarMete

Comment: @DerekF is that as simple as adding the following?:

Comment: Map<Id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>();
        List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>(); @DerekF